# Java data structures query

Tags: data-structures

I have one array or may be any kind of dynamic  data structures to store the integer values into it like [5,3,3,1,2]I just need to get the index of the element first after that it's having most less digits .

Comment: What do you mean by "after that it's having most less digits" ?

Comment: Please show some examples. Given `[5,3,3,1,2]`, what would be the answer? Why?